# Why should I serialize custom exception in c#?

Tags: c#, serialization, exception

I have been using basic c# mainly for Unity3d but recently started picking it up bit more. While reading about idiomatic handling exceptions I came across exception serialization. I am trying to figure out why should I be serializing them.

Here is sample code from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200259/6096446).

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[Serializable]
public class MyException : Exception
{
    // Constructors
    public MyException(string message) 
        : base(message) 
    { }

    // Ensure Exception is Serializable
    protected MyException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt) 
        : base(info, ctxt)
    { }
}
```

I can't see how it could be useful to serialize exceptions. When and why does it make sense to do so?

Comment: Thanks @adriano-repetti

Comment: It's important to add the Serializable attribute which make sure that your exception can be serialized and works correctly across application domains( for example, when a web service return an exception).