# ISerializable and backward compatibility

Tags: .net, backwards-compatibility, binaryformatter, iserializable

I have to work an an old application that used binaryFormatter to serialize application data into filestream (say in a file named "data.oldformat")
without any optimizazion the main class has been marked with  attribute

```
<serializable()>public MainClass
....... 
end class
```

and the serialization code

```
dim b as new binaryformatter
b.serialize(mystream,mymainclass)
```

In an attempt to optimize the serialization/deserialization process I simply made the class implement the ISerializable interface and wrote some optimized serialization routines

```
<serializable()>public MainClass
       implements ISerializable
....... 
end class
```

The optimization works really well but I MUST find a way to reatrive the  data inside the old files for backward compatibility.

How can I do that??

Pierluigi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**stmax** has an excellent answer, however I would implement it like this, which uses `SerializationEntry.GetEnumerator()` instead of `try/catch`. This way is cleaner and significantly faster.

```
public MainClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
    int version = 0;
    foreach (SerializationEntry s in info)
    {
        if (s.Name == "version") 
        {
            version = (int)s.Value;
            break;
        }
    }

    switch (version) {
      case 0:
        // deserialize "old format"
        break;
      case 1:
        // deserialize "new format, version 1"
        break;
      default:
        throw new NotSupportedException("version " + version + " is not supported.");
    }
}
```

I would prefer a LINQ version using .FirstOrDefault(), but SerializationInfo does not implement IEnumerable - in face, weirdly enough, it doesn't even implement the old IEnumerable interface.

Answer (score 4):

since you've already implemented the ISerializable interface, you've probably also already added the required constructor:

```
public MainClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {}
```

you can use the info-object passed to the constructor to retrieve data from the serialized file. **by default (i.e. when no ISerializable is implemented), the fields names are used as identifiers during serialization. so if your old class had a field "int x" you can deserialize this using:**

```
this.x = info.GetInt32("x");
```

for newer versions i normally add a "version" entry during serialization, like this:

```
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
  info.AddValue("version", 1);
  info.AddValue("othervalues", ...);
}
```

during deserialization you can check this version entry and deserialize accordingly:

```
public MainClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
    int version;
    try {
       version = info.GetInt32("version");
    }
    catch {
       version = 0;
    }

    switch (version) {
      case 0:
        // deserialize "old format"
        break;
      case 1:
        // deserialize "new format, version 1"
        break;
      default:
        throw new NotSupportedException("version " + version + " is not supported.");
    }
}
```

i haven't compiled that code, might contain typos.

hope that helps.

Comment: great answer stmax! how did u find the default behaviour for the binaryformatter object?

Comment: i did the following to find the "names" of the entries that were serialized with the default behaviour: foreach (SerializationEntry entry in info.GetEnumerator()) { Trace.WriteLine(entry.Name); }

Comment: Instead of try/catch when getting "version", instead use SerializationInfo.GetEnumerator() and search for the "version" field. It is cleaner and if the field is not found then avoiding throwing the exception makes the entire deserialization (in my testing) 2x faster. SerializationInfo.Get() internally uses the same linear search as doing it yourself with an enumerator, making them both O(n) in the number of fields.

Comment: +1 Good and clean way to preserve backwards compatibility. However, while you are right that field values can be accessed by using the actual field names, this doesn't apply to auto properties. The compiler then uses the format "<PropertyName>k__BackingField". I will add this information to your answer, so you can accept it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Just try the same thing you've been doing so far

```
BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
MainClass a = b.DeSerialize(mystream) as MainClass;
```

Implementing ISerializable didn't change your original class, basically you've just added some methods

Comment: I've added the required constructor (serializationInfo info, streamingContext context) so I can't use b.deserialize without knowing how the main class saved his own data during the default serialization

Answer (score 0):

When serializing your objects add an additional Version field (this shouldn't add too much overhead). Then in your GetObjectData method, try to retrieve the version field first and based on whether this exists or not (by catching the SerializationException) deserialize the old way or the new way. The old way will have just serialized all data so you should just be able to call Get... for all fields.

Comment: this is fine for the serialization procedure which uses getObjectData but the problem is during the deserialization procedure which uses a specialized constructor

new(info as serializationinfo,context as serializationcontext)

the old mainClass version didn't implement ISerializable so I don't know how to retrieve data using the streaminginfo object

Answer (score 0):

Your previous code should work. Do you get an exception? 
Try to use new constructor:

```
 Protected Sub New(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, ByVal context As StreamingContext)
```

Comment: I Had..but It requires to know how the binaryformatter saves data when the class is only marked as serializable...