# Is there a subtle error in this type?

Tags: c#

Found this in our codebase and took a while to figure out (and had to use a debugger). This class does really only one thing but not quite as intended.

Thought I'd share!

**EDIT** Got rid of the syntax error, sorry!

```
public class RecordNotFoundException : ApplicationException
{       
    readonly string _entityName;
    public string EntityName
    {
        get { return _entityName; }
    }

    readonly string _details;

    public override string Message
    {
        get
        {
           return string.Format("Can't find a record for {0}.", _entityName)
            + _details != null ? string.Format(" Details: {0}", _details) : "";
        }
    }

    public RecordNotFoundException(string entityName)
    {
        _entityName = entityName;
    }

    public RecordNotFoundException(string entityName, string details)
        : this(entityName)
    {
        _details = details;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the question? What's the issue/error?

Comment: Voting to close. This question is just silly. You're asking us to figure out what the problem with the code is, and say you had to use the debugger. Well, I didn't, I just had to look at it and spot the problem. You've written the conditional operator wrong in terms of parenthesis. If you really want us to look at a riddle, please get the riddle right.

Comment: This code should not even compile because of punctuation problems in the Message property.

Comment: @tzup, There is a compilation error in your code. In the Message property, the return should be `string.Format("Can't find a record for {0}.", _entityName)
                 + _details != null ? string.Format(" Details: {0}", _details) : "";` and not as in your code. The bracket is misplaced.

Comment: He hasn't posted the *real* code. The code cannot be run in a debugger, the code won't even compile. He's put the else-part of the conditional operator inside the second call to string.Format.

Comment: This is not a real question. I do not see the use of this on the site, except that the OP might be rep farming... **Bad tzup**

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, looks like a misplaced closing parenthesis.

Comment: conditional operators used in a wrong way

Comment: Sorry about the syntax error guys, something happened while formatting...

Comment: It's a Yes | No question. Doesn't matter whether I figured it out in the meantime or not...and I said that I thought I'd share.

Comment: There are lots of sites where you can share 'interesting' things that you inherit :) However, SO is not one of them.

Comment: I'd say that there are at least two problems with the class: 1) it derives from `ApplicationException`, something that is advised against [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception.aspx), 2) It does not implement the recommended constructors to allow for the exception to be serialized [see here for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94488/what-is-the-correct-way-to-make-a-custom-net-exception-serializable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property **Message** will never return a string that starts with *"Can't find a record for..."*

Comment: obviously. The code is adding the result of the first format to _details and checking if it evaluates to null

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is vague, this is your problem, change `Message` property to this:

```
public override string Message
{
    get
    {
       return string.Format("Can't find a record for {0}.", _entityName)
        + _details != null ? string.Format(" Details: {0}", _details): String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the syntax error in the original posting, sorry about that. It should have looked originally the way you wrote it in your answer. The "other" issue is still in there.