# How to serialize .Net Exceptions using Protobuf-Net?

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Can anyone give me an example or point me to a resource on how to use Protobuf-Net to serialize/deserialize some of the bulit-in system classes?

Specifically I'm just trying to serialize/deserialize the base Exception class and all other exception classes that inherit from it.  Will I have to create a new RunTypeModel that specifies every possible exception class that I will ever need to serialize, or can I somehow tell Protobuf-Net to serialize them all the same way without listing every single one?

Any help is very appreciated since I am brand new to Protobuf-Net and I'm still trying to understand it all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

protobuf-net is designed to serialize DTO models, but not exceptions - very similar to XmlSerializer etc (but binary rather than xml, obviously). Serialising exceptions is not currently built in. It may be possible to hack some things, but this isn't really a designed feature.

Comment: I ultimately solved this problem by creating an ExceptionProxy class that uses a little ugly reflection to extract the data from an exception and serialize it.  I then re-hydrate the exception graph on the other side using the deserialized ExceptionProxy class information and more reflection.  It isn't pretty, but it works quite well.

Comment: You can bypass this issue by serializing the Exception as a byte array and then deserialize it in the client side

Answer (score 0):

You really can´t serialize a class like

```
public class MyTest
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Exception MyException { get; set; }
}
```

But doing a small change will be possible to serialize

```
public class MyTest
{
    [ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)]
    public Object MyException { get; set; }
}
```

This was the only way that I found to serialize an exception.

Comment: Tried, this didn't seem to work for me. This worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94488/what-is-the-correct-way-to-make-a-custom-net-exception-serializable