# What exception type to throw if a list/collection is empty or null and cannot be iterated (not a parameter)?

Tags: c#, exception

Suppose a simple example where a method retrieves a collection (such as a list containing some configuration strings) and tries to examine it in some way:

```
void Init()
{
    XmlDocument config = new XmlDocument();
    config.Load(someXml);
    var list = config.SelectNodes("/root/strings/key"); // Normally, list should not be null or empty

    if (list == null || list.Count == 0)
        throw new SomeExceptionType(message);   // What kind of exception to throw?

    // Iterate list and process/examine its elements
    foreach (var e in list) ...
}
```

In this specific instance, the method cannot continue normally if nothing was retrieved. I'm unsure what exception type to throw in such situations. My options are, as far as I know:

- throw nothing manually and let `NullReferenceException` be thrown
  automatically (which doesn't handle empty list situation),
- throw custom exception type (probably not a good idea, as I don't anticipate the caller will try to do anything about the exception,
  i.e. he won't be looking for a speecific exception type to handle),
- do something else?

Comment: Is `/root/strings/key` fix or a variable? Then i would use an `ArgumentException` or use a custom exception type.

Comment: It's fixed, but shouldn't `ArgumentException` only be used in the context of invalid arguments provided to a method (in this case, there are no arguments at all)?

Comment: If the source would be a property you could throw an `ArgumentException` because the setter got an invalid argument, hence `value` would be invalid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create your own exception type for appropriate logic:

```
public class InitializationException : Exception
{
}
```

and then:

```
throw new InitializationException {Message = "Collection is empty"};
```

Comment: I think this is the best way to throw an Exception if you want to. If you don't throw an exception that just handle it by the caller with the NullReferenceException

Comment: What I don't like about deriving custom exceptions that only differ in name and won't be handled at all is 1) code organization issues (where do you put all these declarations if you have the same exception conditions across multiple projects etc.) 2) is this really all that different from simply going heretic and throwing a general Exception(message)?

Comment: I suggest you use typed exception instead of general Exception, coz later you can split catch logic easily.

Comment: It should probably also be noted that a custom exception should support serialization and implement the four basic constructors. See [this](http://csharp.2000things.com/2013/07/26/896-custom-exceptions-should-be-marked-as-serializable/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94488/what-is-the-correct-way-to-make-a-custom-net-exception-serializable)

Answer (score 21):

`Enumerable.First` throws `System.InvalidOperationException` if the collection is empty. So could you, I guess.

```
throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no elements");
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is a single built-in exception you can elegantly throw in this case...a `NullReferenceException` is inappropriate since an empty list is not a null reference

I would suggest going with Dmintry's proposed solution since the caller can still just use `try...catch(Exception)` without having to know or care that the exception is really a `SuperDooperListNullOrEmptyFunTimeException`

Since this is either an unrecoverable error from the caller's point of view (i.e they have no control over the selected Xml path, and no control over what the XML is that's being loaded) then the exception is only going to be either dumped to a log or on-screen for human consumption, at which point it's moot - as the actual message is more important than the type.

On the other hand, if it is recoverable (caller can re-try the method after having made sure that the xml to load now contains the correctly formatted xml, or caller can notify the user and ask them to go and fix the XML and "would you like to retry now?" kind of thing) then you *need* to give them a typed exception so they know it's safe to retry as opposed to a plain old Exception which could mean something else went horribly wrong and retrying will only make things worse...

Comment: There is one - `ConfigurationErrorsException`. `NullReferenceException` is inappropriate because you should not throw, catch, or leave your code throwing it.

Comment: @dstarkowski - interesting point, although that looks more like a framework exception specifically in the context of loading app/web.config settings - my answer was assuming this is some kind of custom xml payload. And it's specifically mentioned that this class shouldn't be instantiated by user code. Still, it's worth considering for sure and certainly if this is loading "classic" .config settings then yes, it should be bubbled out to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

That not much of programming problem as it's a design issue, the reason .NET list object don't throw exceptions when they are empty is because there is a lot of cases where a empty list is an expectable and acceptable situation.

If in the context the list you work with is never supposed to be empty then throw an exception (a custom one)

If however it's possible and logical that list may be empty, why interrupt the whole thing, it's excepted not exceptional, so need for an exception ? A `foreach` loop and an empty list won't throw an exception, the loop simply won't loop.

As for the null possibility (quite rare  for `SelectNodes` if understand well) it's same issue, in some libraries or functions returning a `null` is a normal behavior not an exception.

Comment: I know what you mean, but in this specific case I'm interested in scenarios where it is necessary that a list is not null/empty as that would mean that the steps required for correct initialization/configuration cannot be executed at all (e.g. a crucial system configuration file is broken or missing and no defaults can be used).

Comment: Well then you answered your own question, it's an exceptional situation, outside of the normal flow, it deserve an exception.

Comment: @w128 to add to what I said, it deserve an exception, but I don't think you will find any that fit in this context, so custom exception it is