# How to use constructors in custom exception ?

Tags: c#, exception

I am using custom exception for my application developing in MVC.
I am using below link to use understand how can I handle custom exception.

[Custom Exception Link of msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace epay.Services.ExceptionClasses
{
    public class InvalidInputException : Exception
    {

    public InvalidInputException()
    {

    }

    public InvalidInputException(string message) : base(message)
    {

    }

    public InvalidInputException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner)
    {

    }

    }
}
```

But I am completely confused how to use the these constructor which have message and inner exception as a parameter.

I have code in controller like below...

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(PartyVM PartyVM)
        {
            try
            {
                PartyService partyService = new PartyService();
                var i = partyService.Insert(PartyVM);
                return RedirectToAction("SaveData", PartyVM);

            }
            catch (InvalidInputExceptione e)
            {
                CommonMethod commonMethod = new CommonMethod();
                PartyVM.AccountTypes = commonMethod.GetAccountTypes();

                TempData["error"] = e.Message.ToString() + "Error Message";
                return View("Create", PartyVM);
            }
}
```

Comment: Confused about what? P.s. e.Message is string so you don't need convert to string

Comment: How to use the exception with constructor parameters ?

Comment: It seems to be correctly declared at least. Just remember to also add the protected constructor taking the serialization parameters, which is notoriously missing from your link too. See this too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/100369/2557263

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are constructed before they are `thrown`. The code you shared `catch`es an exception.

You can throw an exception as follows:

```
throw new InvalidInputException("Invalid value for username");
```

The `InnerException` property is used when an exception was caught, but you want to wrap it in your own exception to provide more accurate exception information, for example this validates a `string` value for "Age":

```
public static class Validation
{
    public void ThrowIfAgeInvalid(string ageStr)
    {
        int age;
        try
        {
            // Should use int.TryParse() here, I know :)
            age = int.Parse(ageStr);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // An InnerException which originates to int.Parse
            throw new InvalidInputException("Please supply a numeric value for 'age'", ex);
        }

        if (age < 0 || age > 150)
        {
            // No InnerException because the exception originates to our code
            throw new InvalidInputException("Please provide a reasonable value for 'age'");
        }
    }
}
```

This way while debugging you still have a reference to the original cause of the problem.

Comment: @user1650894 I did not mean to provide copy-paste ready code. The bottom line is, _you_ have to `throw` the exception or it will never appear.

Comment: Not copy pasting , but where to write throw code  ? In exception class or in controller's code ?

Comment: The exception should be thrown as soon as you find out the input is invalid. I'll try to provide another example.

Comment: Sorry, but still not getting ... what I have to type in exception class constructors ?

Comment: Your `InvalidInputException` class looks fine. You don't need to do anything because `message` and `inner` are already relayed to the base class, where they will be accessible via the `Message` and `InnerException` properties.