# Custom Exception handing with Property class in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I know this is already asked question.I need to develop User Defined Exception Handing along with the property class, But i am not retrieving the newly added property(DSMException.cs properties) Exceptions .  I went through these two solutions-

[Custom exception with properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031530/custom-exception-with-properties)

[What is the correct way to make a custom .NET Exception serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94488/what-is-the-correct-way-to-make-a-custom-net-exception-serializable)

I have a `Property` class -DSMException which contains three properties Type,Message, InnerExceptionMessage, which needs to be dsiplayed.

**DSMException.cs**

```
 public class DSMException
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string InnerExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

The Respective custom Exception class is given.

**FatalException.cs**

```
 public class FatalException :Exception
    {
        DSMException exception = new DSMException();
        public FatalException():base()
        {

        }

        public FatalException(string? Message): base(Message)
        {
            exception.Type = "FATAL";
            exception.Message = "MESSAGE:" + Message;
        }

        public FatalException(string? Message,Exception ex) : base(Message,ex)
        {
            exception.Type = "FATAL";
            exception.Message = "MESSAGE: " + ex.Message;
            exception.InnerExceptionMessage = "MORE DET: " + ex.ToInnerMostException().Message;
        }
    }
```

I am throwing exceptions like below code
**Channel.cs**

```
 public override void Run(ServiceSettings settings, DataSource dataSource, string path)
 {
 try
{
  var channel = entities.Channels
         .Where(c => c.Name == parameters.Channel)
         .FirstOrDefault();
    if (channel != null)
      {
        // ANY LOGIC
      }
   else
    {
      throw new FatalException("Invalid Channel Name !!!");
    }
}
 catch (FatalException ex)// for channel is null
 {
     throw ex;
 }
catch (Exception ex)
 {
    throw ex;
 }
}
```

The error raises here during the catching of the Exceptions-FatalExceptions

**FolderInvocation.cs** (Error)

```
 private void DoFolderInvocation(DataSource dataSource, Plugin plugin)
{
  // Do type invocation
try
 {
 result = helper.Invoke(importableFile.Path);// This invokes the Run method, I skipped those codes

 if (result == null)
     logger.WriteError($"{dataSource.Key}: Unknown error while processing file '{importableFile.Path}'.");
else if (result.Success == false)
      logger.WriteError($"{dataSource.Key}: Error while processing file '{importableFile.Path}'. 
      {result.Message}");
 else
     logger.WriteDebug($"{dataSource.Key}: File '{importableFile.Path}' was processed successfully. 
     {result.Message}");
 }
 catch (FatalException exFatal)// **Problem Arises here-> need to get Ex.Type in the FatalException**
 {
   logger.WriteError($"{dataSource.Key}: An error occurred while processing data source: 
   {exFatal.Message}");
    throw exFatal;
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
{
 logger.WriteError($"{dataSource.Key}: Invocation error while processing file '{importableFile.Path}'. 
 {ex.Message}");
}
}
```

What I am missing, as far these minimum reproduced code is correct but I need to get Ex.Type in the FatalException. Kindly advice me.

Comment: What problem "Arises here"? Can you please add error text?

Comment: Your `DSMException  exception` is private. It can't be accessed outside instance of `FatalException`, and it is field, not property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to forward the fields as public properties:

```cs
public class FatalException: Exception
{
    private readonly DSMException _exception = new DSMException();

    /* ... snip ... */

    public string MyType => _exception.Type;
    public string MyMessage => _exception.Message;
    public string MyInnerExceptionMessage => _exception.InnerExceptionMessage;
}
```

It does seem to defeat the purpose of the `DSMException` class a bit however. You *could* make the `DSMException` a public property, but I'd strongly suggest to make it immutable beforehand.

I obviously don't know the intended purpose of the `DSMException` class, however since all values are assembled in the constructors anyway, you could also directly assign to public properties:

```
public FatalException(string? Message): base(Message)
{
    Type = "FATAL";
    Message = "MESSAGE:" + Message;
}

public string MyType { get ; }
public string MyMessage { get ; }
public string MyInnerExceptionMessage { get ; }
```

---

To continue on the immutability suggestion: You could define your `DSMException` class like so:

```cs
public sealed class DSMException
{
    public DSMException(string type, string message, string innerMessage)
    {
        Type = type;
        Message = message;
        InnerExceptionMessage = innerMessage;
    }

    public string Type { get; }
    public string Message { get; }
    public string InnerExceptionMessage { get; }
}
```

... and then just make it a public property:

```cs
public class FatalException: Exception
{
    /* ... snip ... */

    public DSMException DSM => _exception;
}
```

It does appear that you still have to duplicate most of the constructor code across `FatalException`, `ErrorException`, `WarningException` etc.

Also note that as long as your custom exceptions only fly around in the same AppDomain, everything is fine; the moment they may cross domain boundaries (e.g. by wire), `DSMException` needs to be serializable and the serialization methods of your custom exceptions would need to be implemented as well.

Comment: There are four other types of User Defined Exceptions -namely FatalException, InfoException, WarningException,ErrorException. I created DSMExceptions.cs to handle these four types of exceptions with reduced code.

Comment: Would you mind to edit my code ? since there is some errors during initializing part of FatalExceptions.cs.

Comment: It wouldn't be much of a question if it had code working as expected. :)) Could you add some details about the errors you're observing (to your question)?