# WebApi can't serialize attribute declared on derived class from Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I can´t get the properties values created on BaseException when call to Get api method. Any idea why?

```
public class BaseException : Exception
{
    public  string ExType { get; set; }

    public JObject Properties { get; set; }

    public Guid ErrorCodeId { get; set; }

    public BaseException(string message): base(message) { }
}

public class BadRequestException : BaseException
{
    public BadRequestException(string message) : base(message) { }
}

// GET: api/<controller>
public virtual IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    IHttpActionResult result = null;
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Error description here");
        result = Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new BadRequestException(ex.Message)
        {
            ExType = "Any exception type"//Can't get this value in the output JSON
        }));
    }
    return result;
}
```

ExType value is not showing. The result that I got is the following:

```
{
  "ClassName": "BadRequestException",
  "Message": "Error description here",
  "Data": null,
  "InnerException": null,
  "HelpURL": null,
  "StackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": null,
  "HResult": -2146233088,
  "Source": null,
  "WatsonBuckets": null
}
```

There is any way to get the serealized value of my own properties?

Answer (score 0):

Well regarding to this answer [What is the correct way to make a custom .NET Exception serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/100369/2547429)
.

Is needed to explicitly add the new properties when serializing an object of custom inherited class from Exception.
To do that we should override the **GetObjectData** method and put into info all properties and values that you want to serialize.

```
public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    base.GetObjectData(info, context);
}
```

Great, so to automate that we could use reflection as follows

```
public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    //Getting first from base
    base.GetObjectData(info, context);

    if (info != null)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            //Adding only properties that not already declared on Exception class
            if (property.DeclaringType.Name != typeof(Exception).Name)
            {
                info.AddValue(property.Name, property.GetValue(this));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then when serializing all custom properties apear in the output.