# Add extra properties in Custom Exception to return to AJAX function

Tags: vb.net, exception, custom-errors, custom-error-handling

I have a custom exception class as follows:

```
<Serializable>
Public Class SamException
    Inherits Exception
    Public Sub New()
        ' Add other code for custom properties here.
    End Sub
    Public Property OfferBugSend As Boolean = True

    Public Sub New(ByVal message As String)
        MyBase.New(message)
        ' Add other code for custom properties here.
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal message As String, ByVal inner As Exception)
        MyBase.New(message, inner)
        ' Add other code for custom properties here.
    End Sub

End Class
```

I'm using this for certain cases in returns from AJAX responses.

In the error function of my AJAX response I am determining that the error is of my custom type like this:

```
.... 
ajax code....
.error = function (xhr, text, message) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var isSamCustomError = (parsed.ExceptionType).toLowerCase().indexOf('samexception') >= 0;
 .... etc....
```

This allows me to post back a specific response to the client if the error is of my custom type.

BUT... I can't seem to get it to post out the extra property `OfferBugSend` to the client for the AJAX code to handle this case differently.

```
console.log("OfferBugSend: " + parsed.OfferBugSend)
```

is showing undefined, and if I check the response, this is because `xhr.responseText` only contains the properties:

```
ExceptionType
Message
StackTrace
```

These properties are from the base class `Exception` but it is not passing my custom class properties...

How can I make that happen?

Comment: Please attach a code example how you submit your AJAX and throw your `SamException`.

Comment: I would advise try catch the code you want. If you hit your exception, throw that exception up from the BLL/DAL into your Presentation layer. In your presentation layer, provide a way to Return the New exception type that will be converted FROM your exception. Example is, try catch (special exception){ return new {.SpecialMessage="IamError",.IsError=True}. In your Ajax, check for IsError.

Answer (score 3):

The Exception class is serializable, but it contains an IDictionary and implements ISerializable, which requires a little more work for serializing your custom Exception Class.

The easier way to deal with this is by leveraging the [Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) collection of the Exception class like so:

```
Public Property OfferBugSend As Boolean
    Get
        Return Data("OfferBugSend")
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        Data("OfferBugSend") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Another way to do this is to ensure your derived class also implements the [ISerializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, which involves providing a serialization constructor and overriding GetObjectData().  See this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/100369/341762) (in C#) as a baseline for that approach.